# retrieving a updated list of countries states and cities in a website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to create a User Registration page in ASP.NET and wondering what
is the best way to get the list of up-to-date Countries and Cities? Are
there any Web Services on the web that I can use to retrieve such
information? If not, what are the options?

Please, any suggestions and pointers will be very much appreciated

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332685/is-there-a-centralized-list-of-country-names-that-can-be-used-for-web-drop-down-b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? http://www.maxmind.com/app/web_services_country_usage

I have not tried it myself though.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [angrymonkeycloud.com/geography](https://www.angrymonkeycloud.com/geography) to get full list of countries and their states (subdivision).

You can even get countries primary language and currency to set it as your users default settings.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of sources for the information on complete lists of countries and major cities. The United Nations Statistics Division's annual demographic yearbook has a list of major cities > 100K population in CSV format:

http://unstats.un.org/unsd/demographic/products/dyb/dyb2012/Table08.xls

The CIA World Factbook also has a list of major cities in the world at:

https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2219.html

They also keep a list of bitmap images for the corresponding country flags:

https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/docs/flagsoftheworld.html

I also keep a large links and copies of these types of datasets in our own custom CSV format at this URL:

http://www.opengeocode.org/cude1.1/index.php

Comment: If you want to use international codes for cities, I would suggest using the UN's LOCODE system or IATA for cities that have an international airport.

Answer (score -1):

Yes I worked for an organization that used this: http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/english_country_names_and_code_elements.htm for countries; there are other sources too that are valid that I can't currently find.  There are state code lists but I haven't seen city.  I've not seen any web services offerings; the one listed below was news to me...

We typically attempted to standardize with these codes, loaded them into a database, and even had a central database with these values that other DB's referenced too.

HTH.